# Compare variance between 2 group and within group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance

I have 2 groups of patients. Each group has 22 patients. I wish to compare the variance in bladder volume for each patients from planning bladder volume (referance) to weekly bladder volume (week 1, week 2, week3, week 4 and week 5) in group 1 and group 2.

```
Group 1
             PLANNING BV  WEEK 1  WEEK 2   WEEK 3    WEEK 4   WEEK 5
patient 1    132           100      127     156       120      100
patient 2    150           148      153     176       101      171 
patient 3    140           110      167     117       154      162
```

I also wish to determine which group has more variance. I am not comparing means because I find there is a large variation between each week.

Comment: Consider computing the variance by group and date and plotting the variance by date--one plot per group.  *Use a cube-root axis to display the variance.*  (Equivalently, plot the cube roots of the variances against date.) How do the plots compare?